# How can I show a picture in a gridview row without saving it to the hard drive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i'm creating a shopping website. i have a gridview that is bound to an objectdatasource control for administration tasks. this grid is responsible for showing the items table in a sql server database. each item also might or might not have a picture. so when this grid is shown to the admin i want a small thumbnail of the associated image to be available for each row. here is the gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" 
   DataSourceID="objDataSource" DataKeyNames="item_id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="item_category" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField HtmlEncode="true" DataField="item_name" 
            HeaderText="Item Name" />
        <asp:BoundField HtmlEncode="true" NullDisplayText="Not Set" 
            DataField="item_desc" HeaderText="Item Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Picture"
            ItemStyle-Width="40px" ItemStyle-Height="40px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <!-- here should be the image -->
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowSelectButton="True"
            HeaderText="Selecting" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

i'm only aware of two options when it comes to showing image in the browsers:

- save a bitmap on the response stream. this will not be inside of gridview when it renders to client(correct?).
- save a bitmap on hard drive after the select statement and use an image control inside of template then assign the ImageUrl attribute dynamically.

second option is too expensive because it needs writing and reading on a hard drive for each image(or datarow). so how can i do this? is it even possible?

**ps:** ajax is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an ASP.NET Web Handler (.ashx file) that handles your image, pass the id of the image to your gridview and create a "link" to that image handler that will either display the image if it exists, or possibly display a 'no image available' image

Here is a quick tutorial on ASHX files: http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

I can post additional code if you need it

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to put the raw image data inline in the HTML. It's not a common technique, but it does work - see http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/ for details.

Some things to bear in mind: this doesn't work on all browsers - IE7 and older don't support this, for example, as far as I know. Also, this is not a very space-efficient way to send a bitmap, so unless they're really tiny, this is a terrible idea. (Although for sufficiently tiny bitmaps, it's possible for the HTTP overhead involved in a separate download to be slightly worse than the overhead for inline images. Also, if you can enable compression for HTTP pages on your server, then inline bitmaps look slightly less bad.)

But in general, you're probably better off with the separate handler proposed by Anthony Shaw. That's likely to be a better solution unless these really are very small images.

Comment: +1 IE7 is between 4% and 6% of the worldwide browser market, and since this is for an administration tool, if Jim wants to specify the product supports IE8 and later, this could be a very quick, easily viable solution. I was about to post the same, but you beat me to it. However, [Anthony Shaw](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9362925/416518)'s response really is the way to go, especially since it allows you the option to pass in image dimensions as query string parameters to reduce download size.